# OSX keyboard shortcut for pushing button with underlined character

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

Is it possible on OSX to push buttons that have an underlined character? In Windows you can hold in ALT and push the key that is underlined on the button.

Example:
[image]

On Windwos I can hit the "Replace"-button by hitting ALT+p, the "Replace all"-button by hitting ALT+a, etc.

How can I achieve this on a mac?

Comment: Alt is used for special characters on a Mac, so I think you would have to use another key like command or control.

Comment: Most Mac apps don't have this feature, and as such, it is not part of the OS—meaning it's your app only that's doing it, and it might not work at all. If you tell us what it is maybe we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

On my Macbook Pro with external keyboard and PHPStorm workd CTRL+ALT+P. 
But, before try this shortcut, you need remove from phpstorm internal shortcuts.