# Underlined letters in dialog box (Krita)

Tags: keyboard, windows, shortcut

In a save as file dialog box in the Application Krita, some of the buttons are underlined with a letter.  In Windows, if your press alt and the underlined letter, this presses the button.  Is there anyway to do this in the Krita dialog boxes such as the save dialog?

From [OSX keyboard shortcut for pushing button with underlined character](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171745/osx-keyboard-shortcut-for-pushing-button-with-underlined-character), I am beginning to think that the underlines are usually for Windows, yet one user suggested we share the name of the app we are using.  (Thus I mention Krita)

I see that I can use the tab key to move around within a dialog box, but I just want to use those underlined letters.
([How to interact with dialog boxes using keyboard that appear not to allow keyboard interaction?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71645/how-to-interact-with-dialog-boxes-using-keyboard-that-appear-not-to-allow-keyboa))

I am also not asking about Menus here, which are really easy to use in mac ([Is it possible to enable underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371514/is-it-possible-to-enable-underline-keyboard-shortcuts-and-access-keys)), but rather the dialog box buttons.

Is there some trick for hitting underlined letters in crossplatform apps like Krita on the Mac?  I have searched on Google with several combinations of "alt underlined keyboard shortcut mac and windows" and I cannot find anything on this subject.  It would be nice to just have a definitive statement that these are just red herrings and ignore them.  Or better yet if there is a way.